# Facebook Graph API - Search places fail

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I use following codes to get places information with my location in Facebook iOS SDK.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search?type=place&center=%f,%f&distance=200&limit=100&offset=0", la, lo] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error.localizedDescription:%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

    NSArray *list = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"list:%@", list);
}];
```

These works fine before, but fails today. This is error message.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

I go to facebook API page.(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/)

And, I find https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000 return nil.

So, I try to figure out whether this problem is due to facebook, and the thing I only can do is waiting?

Answer (score 1):

Using The latest SDK

```
NSMutableDictionary *params2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3L];

    [params2 setObject:@"37.416382,-122.152659" forKey:@"center"];
    [params2 setObject:@"place" forKey:@"type"];
    [params2 setObject:@"1000" forKey:@"distance"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/search" parameters:params2 HTTPMethod:@"GET"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE!!! /search");
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    }];
```